# Generate fixed name with increment number

Tags: sql, postgresql

I use this SQL query to generate test data into column:

```
INSERT into onboarding_tasks SELECT generate_series(1,355) AS id,
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS business_name;
```

What is the proper way to generate Strings like this for column `business_name`:

```
ABC name 1
ABC name 2
ABC name 3
ABC name 4
```

etc...
I would like to have a fixed name + increasing number for every next table row record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate:

```
edb=# create table mytable (id int, name text);
CREATE TABLE
edb=# insert into mytable values (generate_series(1,10),'ABC name ' || generate_series(1,10));
INSERT 0 10
edb=# select * from mytable ;
 id |    name     
----+-------------
  1 | ABC name 1
  2 | ABC name 2
  3 | ABC name 3
  4 | ABC name 4
  5 | ABC name 5
  6 | ABC name 6
  7 | ABC name 7
  8 | ABC name 8
  9 | ABC name 9
 10 | ABC name 10
(10 rows)
```